# How to add logging to Apache If/Else?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

No matter what, Apache is always going to the else block. I've looked at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462011/htaccess-if-else-always-selects-else), but this one is using a user-defined environment variable. I'm trying to use an apache header to do some dynamic includes.. I've read some mixed things about dynamic includes (it might not be possible?). Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/^.*my-wanted-string.*">
    Include myconf1.conf
</If>
<Else>
    Include myconf2.conf
</Else>
```

Is this possible to do in apache 2.4? I'd like to check the logging of REQUEST_URI to confirm that it's not empty because nothing matches.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not terminated. You specified a delimiter `#` but it never appears at the end of your regex.

Further, it then contains a `/` followed by a `^`, which means the beginning of a string. This can never match because the `/` precedes it. Of course since you have a greedy match `.*` following the `/` and are working with a URL path, the `/` is superfluous and can itself be omitted. The matches themselves are also superfluous in this particular scenario.

You should add the delimiter to the end of the regex, remove the stray `^` character, and possibly other things. Since you didn't specify what you were trying to do, it may not be possible to advise further.

Something like this will probably get you closer to where you are going:

```
 <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#my-wanted-string#">
```

Comment: So I'm trying to see if it even matches anything: which is `m#^/(.*)$#` ? Even this still goes to the else block... This is why I'd like to do something like `echo %{REQUEST_URI}` and check that it's not empty...

Comment: @nodel If REQUEST_URI is empty then you've got bigger problems than this regex!

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work, since doesn't `.*` match even an empty string? How can I echo this header?

Comment: That doesn't match just an empty string, though. It matches a `/` at the beginning of the string followed by some text. And you can put the string in the access log, but it's already there!

Comment: Even `m#^(.*)$#` goes into the else.. Is there an alternative way to do this with ENV instead of If/Else?